# GIT command: How can I update (pull) another branch while I am on another branch? So I wont need to checkout and pull the former

Tags: git, version-control

Say, I am in a feature/branch and before i push i wanted to merge develop to feature/branch. Currently this is what i do.

Currently on feature branch.

1. checkout develop
2. pull develop to update from origin
3. checkout again feature branch
4. merge develop to feature branch

Basically, wanted to execute #1 and #2 without leaving the feature branch.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just do a `git fetch` to update the local tracking branch for `develop`, and then merge that into `feature`:

```
git checkout feature
git fetch origin    # update origin/develop
get merge origin/develop
```

This works by eliminating the `git pull` step, which would have done this:

```
git checkout develop
git fetch origin
git merge origin/develop
```

You don't actually need to update your local `develop` branch, since the tracking branch already has the latest information.